# Excel spread sheet form pop

Tags: microsoft-excel

Having said that there must be a way to copy data into an existing form with a single entry, i.e. if there are a number of employees with recurring training information set in a spread sheet it should be possible to copy that info into an existing form.

I understand that cells are identified by an alpha and numerical number A1, what I want to do is simply enter the number which identifies the line to the employee and have the fields on the form sheet auto populate.  The formulas within the form sheet are written with the alpha portion of the applicable cell.

What I want to do is simply enter a number that corresponds with an employees line of data and it populates all areas of the form with a single entry to ease the repetition of filling out numerous forms manually.

Comment: You want to do it in one single entry. Can you show the code you used to make it in multiple entries?

Answer (score 1):

That is extremely basic excel functionality - The number of ways to accomplish this are too numerous to list - one of the ways you can accomplish what you are trying to do is with a VLOOKUP function. For future reference - this question probably belongs on superuser - you will get better responses there. I'm going to flag it as such. Example is below:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]